# after save not direct to original page

Tags: php, html

This code is for save the data after key in form meeting. But when it's save it doesn't bring back to the original page. 
It just showing blank page.

```
$datetime=date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime($_POST['datetime']));
$type=$_POST['meeting_type'];
$bilno=$_POST['bilno']; 
$total_agenda=$_POST['total_agenda'];
    $tablename="meeting_info";
    $sql_ins="INSERT INTO meeting_info(datetime, type, bilno, total_agenda) VALUES ( '$datetime','$type','$bilno', '$total_agenda')";
    $conn->query($sql_ins);

    $sql_id = "SELECT id FROM meeting_info ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql_id);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        // output data of each row
        if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $id=$row["id"];
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='administration.php?id='.$id;</script>";  
        }
    }
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to redirect using

```
header("location:administration.php?id=".$id);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{               
   header("refresh:1;url=index.php");
   exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
header("location:administration.php?id=".$id);
```

instead of echoing the url

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for your question hope this will help you

```
$datetime=date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime($_POST['datetime']));
$type=$_POST['meeting_type'];
$bilno=$_POST['bilno']; 
$total_agenda=$_POST['total_agenda'];
    $tablename="meeting_info";
    $sql_ins="INSERT INTO meeting_info(datetime, type, bilno, total_agenda) VALUES ( '$datetime','$type','$bilno', '$total_agenda')";
    $conn->query($sql_ins);

    $sql_id = "SELECT id FROM meeting_info ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql_id);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        // output data of each row
        if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $id=$row["id"];
           echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='administration.php?id=".$id."';</script>";  
        }
    }
$conn->close();
```